# TinyMCE and Laravel 5.3 TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel-5, tinymce, csrf, tinymce-4

I'm trying to implement TinyMCE image uploads, using Laravel 5.3 on the server side:

here is my JS for TinyMCE, which is currently in a blade template:

```
<script src="{{ URL::to("/tinymce/tinymce.min.js") }}"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
        relative_urls: false,

        image_title: true,

        automatic_uploads: true,

        images_upload_url: '/discussions/save_images/',

        file_picker_types: 'image',

        images_upload_credentials: true,

        file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
            input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];
                var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
                blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
            };
            input.click();
        }
    });
</script>﻿
```

My route to handle the POST request made by TinyMCE:

```
Route::post("/discussions/save_images/", 'Discussion\DiscussionController@saveImages');
```

My action to handle each upload:

```
public function saveImages(Request $request) {
    $filename = sha1(uniqid()).'.'.request()->file("name")->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file("name")->move('/images/discussions/', $filename);
    return json_encode(["location"=>"/images/discussions/".$filename]);
}
```

Laravel throws a TokenMismatchException. How can I pass the CSRF token into the POST request that TinyMCE makes?

I know that in general this token can be accessed in a template via `{{ csrf_token }}`, but I'm not sure about the correct configuration in regards to TinyMCE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing a custom handler with images_upload_handler and setting the X-CSRF-Token in the request header worked. Here is what the complete JS code ended up looking like:

```
tinymce.init({
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        selector: 'textarea',
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', '/discussions/save_images');
            var token = document.getElementById("_token").value;
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var json;
                if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }
                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                    failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }
                success(json.location);
            };
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            xhr.send(formData);
        },
        file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
            input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];
                var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
                blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
            };
            input.click();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can add csrf token to any xhr request using code below:

```
  $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, xhr) {
      var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

      if (token) {
          return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
      }
  });
```

Comment: seems like an excellent solution, but the header is not being added.